# Merge commit without parent

Tags: git, git-merge

Let's say I have the following commits in my master:

```
master  : ---A----B----C----D---E
```

Now I need to create new branch from commit A and include only changes in commit C

```
master  : ---A----B----C----D---E
              \        
branch2 :      \-------C
```

So I need to put in my branch2  commit C without B

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [cherry-pick](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html)

```
git checkout -b branch2 <shaSUM of A>
git cherry-pick <shaSUM of C>
```

Comment: Note that this won't actually merge the commit itself, but a new commit which contains the same changes as that original commit. In some cases you may want to merge the "actual" commit, in order to avoid later merge conflicts. In that case you would have to merge the commit and its parents, and then revert the unwanted parent commits (such as B) on the new branch. But then you have to be very careful because when you later merge master to branch2, it will ignore commits such as B, because it was "already" merged.